# ios 9 core spotlight search not working for certain strings CSSearchableItemAttributeSet

Tags: ios, spotlight, corespotlight

I have successfully (sort of) implemented spotlight indexing in my iPhone app but certain search strings do not seem to be able to be searched.

I create each CSSearchableItemAttributeSet as type kUTTypeText, I set the display name, title as "D0010".  I also set the keywords to include "D0010" as well. (there are a few hundred with an incrementing number e.g. D0011, D0012 ...)

The app completed the indexing without error.

When I goto the spotlight search and type "D0"  I get three or so results back, as i continue to type "D001" i get no results.

Funny thing is if I type "0010" i get the exact result!

Has anyone any idea whats going on?

Partial Objective C code below.

```
attributeSet.displayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [dataflow flowCounter]];

    attributeSet.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [dataflow flowCounter]];
    //Sounds similar to displayName but is not displayed to user

    attributeSet.contentDescription = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [dataflow flowDescription]];

    attributeSet.keywords = @[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [dataflow flowCounter]],[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"D%@", [dataflow flowNumber]],[dataflow flowCounter], attributeSet.displayName, attributeSet.contentDescription,[dataflow flowNumber],[dataflow flowCounter] ];



    CSSearchableItem *item1 = [[CSSearchableItem alloc] initWithUniqueIdentifier:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"DTC_%@", [dataflow flowNumber]] domainIdentifier:@"com.utiligroup" attributeSet:attributeSet];
```

........

```
    [[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] indexSearchableItems:[self.spotlightsearch copy]
                                               completionHandler: ^(NSError * __nullable error)  {
    if (error != nil ){
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"dataflows added ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Stand down, I knew that adding  the indexSearchableItems only flagged the items for indexing (even when successful return on completion handler) but I didnt realise quite how long it would take ios to index them.

1 day later and all the items are now searchable.

So basically, it just takes some time.